# Why is $location not accessible in this controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As said in the question, `$location` service is not accessible in the controller at the `debugger` point.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    return angular.module('dashboard.controllers').controller(
    'projectController', 
    ['$route', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$location', '$rootScope',
    'ProjectDataService', 'UserService', 

    function($route, $routeParams,$scope, $location, $rootScope,
    ProjectDataService, UserService) 
    {
        return ProjectDataService.loadProjectData().then(function(d) {
            $scope.projectSearch = "";
            $scope.projects = ProjectDataService.getProjectData();
            debugger;
        });
    }
  ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit here is Closures. I would suggest taking a quick look at [Mozilla's MDN article on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

In your case, the anonymous function passed to `then()` is the closure. Since you haven't used `$location` in the scope of your anonymous function, it isn't available when the anonymous function is executed. Therefore, you are unable to see the value in the debugger.

If you were to use `$location` inside the scope of the anonymous function, you would then see it available inside the debugger as it would be in scope.

Comment: How should I close over it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell here. $location is correctly imported. But a question to the submittor: Why are you using the $(document).ready(...) stuff? There is no need for that.

Comment: @kju - I updated the answer to give a little background on the concept of closures and the scope that they create. Hopefully it makes a little more sense now.

Comment: @kju I use doc.ready because I have got separated in different files and you can tell which will load first.

Comment: @JustinNiessner I understand the concept of closures but still... The submitter said that "$location" is not available at the "debugger" point but if I'm not totally mistaken it actually would be available at that point if actually used in the code there, right?

Comment: @kju - You're correct. If the OP actually used `$location` in the closure, it would be available. Instead, the OP is setting a breakpoint without using `$location` but still expecting to see it in the scope of the closure.